# npm script start production build with hash

Tags: node.js, webpack

When building a webpack production version of my server, I use a hash in the filename to separate different builds from one another.

The name of the file would be something like:

```
server.5eff6913d2d4ac0c39e1.js
```

From the command prompt it's easy to start my server app.
Is there a way to do this dynamically from an npm script (i.e. automatically take the latest version)?

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by cleaning the output folder before rebuilding (webpack plugin) and using

```
"build:server:prod": "webpack --config webpack.server.prod.config.js",
"build:client:prod": "webpack --config webpack.client.prod.config.js",
"start:server:prod": "export NODE_ENV=production && node ./dist/server.*.js",
"start:iso:prod": "npm run build:client:prod && npm run build:server:prod && npm run start:server:prod"
```